# Counting Bigram frequency

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, nltk, export-to-csv

I have a 3 column CSV that looks like this :

```
Comment                   Comment Author       Location
As for the requirement    David                ON
The sky is blue           Martin               SK
As for the assignment     David                ON
As for the request        Eric                 QC 
As for the request        Eric                 QC
```

Based on this CSV, I have created a code that allows me to split the comments column into bigrams and count how frequently they appear. However, it does not group it based on the Comment Author and Location columns.

My current code is producing an output csv that looks like this

```
Word         Frequency           Comment Author       Location
As for            4                 David                ON
the request       2                 Martin               SK
the assignment   1                  David                ON
the sky         1                   Eric                 QC
is blue        1                    Eric                 QC
```

My desired output CSV should look like this

```
Word         Frequency           Comment Author       Location
As for            2                 David                ON
As for            2                 Eric                 QC
the request       2                 Eric                 QC
the requirement  1                  David                ON
the sky         1                   Martin               SK
is blue        1                    Martin               SK
```

I've tried using df.groupby but it's not giving me the output I want. I have imported stop words in my code, but for example sake above, I have kept the stop words.  My code looks like this:

```
import nltk
import csv
import string
import re
from nltk.util import everygrams
import pandas as pd


from collections import Counter

from itertools import combinations

df = pd.read_csv('modified.csv', 'r', encoding="utf8", index_col=False, header=None, delimiter=",",
                 names=['comment','Comment Author', 'Location'])

top_N = 100000
stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
# RegEx for stopwords
RE_stopwords = r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(stopwords))

txt = df.comment.str.lower().str.replace(r'\|', ' ').str.cat(sep=' ')

words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(txt)
words = [w for w in words if not w in stopwords]

bigrm = list(nltk.bigrams(words))



word_dist = nltk.FreqDist([' '.join(x) for x in bigrm])
rslt = pd.DataFrame(word_dist.most_common(top_N),
                columns=['Word', 'Frequency'])
rslt['Comment Author'] = df['Comment Author']
rslt['Location'] = df['Location']
print(rslt)
rslt.to_csv('bigram3.csv',index=False)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from flashtext import KeywordProcessor
import nltk
from collections import Counter

# creating dataframe :
df = pd.DataFrame([['As per the requirement','ON','David'],['The sky is blue','SK','Martin'],['As per the assignment','ON','David'],['As per the request','QC','Eric'],['As per the request','QC','Eric']],columns = ['comments', 'location','Author'])



#creating a bigram token
txt = df.comments.str.lower().str.replace(r'\|', ' ').str.cat(sep=' ')
words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(txt)
bigram = list(nltk.bigrams(words))
bigram_token = [' '.join(x) for x in bigram]

#now use flashtext for extracting bigram token from comments
kp = KeywordProcessor()
kp.add_keywords_from_list(bigram_token)

# groupby on author and location 
groupby_element =  list(df.groupby(['Author', 'location']))

data =[]
for i in range(len(groupby_element)):
    author = groupby_element[i][0][0]
    location = groupby_element[i][0][1]
    text = groupby_element[i][1]['comments'].str.lower().str.replace(r'\|', ' ').str.cat(sep=' ')
    data.append((author,location,text))

#groupby dataframe 
groupby_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Author','location','text'])
groupby_df['bigram_token_count'] = groupby_df['comment'].apply(lambda x: Counter(kp.extract_keywords(x)))

 #o/p
 Author location                                          text                                 bigram_token_count
 0   David       ON  as per the requirement as per the assignment  {'as per': 2, 'the requirement': 1, 'the assig...
 1    Eric       QC         as per the request as per the request                    {'as per': 2, 'the request': 2}
 2  Martin       SK                               the sky is blue                       {'the sky': 1, 'is blue': 1}
```

you can also use Countvectorizer

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import  CountVectorizer
vect =  CountVectorizer(ngram_range = (2,2))
bigram_df = pd.DataFrame(vect.fit_transform(groupby_df['text']).todense(), columns = vect.get_feature_names())

final_df = pd.concat([groupby_df[['Author', 'location']],bigram_df], axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely something I can play around with. However, I don't want the text included in my output, only the bigram count. How would I go about doing that? Also I want each word count in it's own column and not as a list.

Comment: @BorkHampton added another way , hope this will help you